# saving server response to local in android device

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting this as my server response.And I want to store all it in device so that the user's session has to be created and stored on the device so that further login to the app is not required. If the user logs out of the app, then this data has to be deleted.
I am stuck here....please tell me a way to solve this problem.

```
    03-20 13:18:56.486 20338-20537/? D/Null: Params :{data[User][password]=pfrt1fKLkoZhAT6hoMJFiA==
                                         , data[User][email]=RyUMRBg7UyeIlFBBtNemZFuG46PJtAIdiZWXnlJ4zNI=
                                         }
03-20 13:18:56.609 20338-20338/? D/Null: Reponse Check :{"code":200,"user":{"User":{"id":"ui1bJkK19jxbaquTboA2oQ==","email":"RyUMRBg7UyeIlFBBtNemZFuG46PJtAIdiZWXnlJ4zNI=","status":"1","verified":"1","created":"2016-03-07 11:41:59","modified":"2016-04-07 15:43:43","token":"6b987332b77d7c69d76bf7be80a85177fb7fa08d"},"Profile":{"id":"1","first_name":"Pradeep","last_name":"Gupta","bio":"sfafaf","address":"82, Debinibash Road\r\nDum Dum, P.O. - Motijheel","phone":"+913325505055","profile_pic":"\/img\/356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab\/license.jpg","user_id":"1","Contributor":{"id":"31","profile_id":"1","status":"1","vs_cdn_id":"261961777","secret_token":"s-7Va5z","uploaded_on":null,"statement":"AOK KJDHKJDH bkgkg kkhkjh kjhkj kjh kjhkjh","time":"7 hours per month","created":"2016-05-02 18:40:11","modified":"2016-05-02 18:41:29"},"Moderator":[]},"redirect":"\/"}}
03-20 13:18:56.695 20338-20338/? D/Null: Object Check :ModelObject{code='200', id='null', email='null', first_name='null', last_name='null'}
03-20 13:18:56.695 20338-20338/? D/Null: Object Check :class com.example.user.myapplication.ModelObject
```

Comment: Use `Realm` or `SharedPreferences` based on the amount of data to be stored

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by use SharedPreferences.

SAVE Data :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
SharedPreferences.Editor data = preferences.edit();
data.putString("loginInfo", yourLoginObjectString);
data.commit();
```

READ data :

```
String loginObjectString = preferences.getString("loginInfo", "defaultValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider any unique field from the response for e.g. email or id or name which will be different for each user and save it in SharedPreferences (local device storage) in the following way..

**Setting values in Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Pradeep");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```

When user logs out of the app, set that field to null. 
Each time the app is launched check if the saved field exists or not(null check). 
Thats it.